# How to convert html to jsx whilst also converting <a> tags to <Link> tags

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a bunch of html content in a database which includes many embedded local links.

I need to render this content using react. However I also want to convert any local links to react-router `<Link>` tags.

I could use dangerouslySetInnerHTML. However I am unsure how best to convert the links.

I've also found a few packages such as [htmltojsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmltojsx). However I am unsure as to the best way to convert the links with these packages.

This must be a fairly common problem, how is it usually solved?

Comment: What is the benefit of convert `a` tag to `Link`?
do you want to overwrite `href`?
what do you think about use `cheerio` and then map your html to react component?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio

Comment: I want to convert to Link so that react-router will take control of them and just re-render the relevant components rather than reload the page.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about cheerio,

Comment: i think use cheerio is good here
so you can apply selectors and build your jsx components view from html
i don't know if there is better way

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio
i'm using it to parse data from html, and you can do the same to build your react components

Comment: I can't find anything that would convert cheerio objects into a React jsx objects. No mention of react or jsx in the cheerio repository or issues.

Comment: i think you do that manually!
for example.. if you get `a` tag convert it to `Link`